# Selecting <li> to be added to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of `<li>` I was wondering how I can click and select them to be pushed onto my array.

For example,

```
          <li class="browser_list">
            <ul>
              <li id="config_3"> Chrome 29</li>
              <li id="config_4"> Chrome 31</li>
              <li id="config_5"> Chrome 33</li>
              <li id="config_6"> Chrome 35</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

array:

```
arr = [];
```

Can vary from size 0-4 depending on what I click

I want to be able to select or unselect (with highlighting) and add config_3, config_4, config_5, config_6 to an array for later use.

Comment: Start by reading about [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), then continue with [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Use checkboxes? sometimes the easy solution is best

Comment: depending on what your use case is, simply toggling a class may be all you need and then use jQuery to map array when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution in pure Javascript.

Alongside the snippet below, here's the same in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qxs6hgj/

```js
var list = document.getElementById('browser_list');
var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    items[i].onclick = function(event)
    {
        if (this.className == 'selected')
        {
            this.className = 'unselected';
            var idx = arr.indexOf(this.id);
            if (idx >= 0)
                arr.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.className = 'selected';
            arr[arr.length] = this.id;
        }
        document.getElementById('arr').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
    };
}
```

```css
#browser_list li { cursor: pointer; }
.selected { background-color: #cccccc; }
.deselected { background-color: transparent; }
```

```html
<ul id='browser_list'>
    <li id="config_3"> Chrome 29</li>
    <li id="config_4"> Chrome 31</li>
    <li id="config_5"> Chrome 33</li>
    <li id="config_6"> Chrome 35</li>
</ul>
<div id='arr'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = []
$("#browser_list > ul").click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).is("li")){
       arr.push(event.target)
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggle classes and check arrays:

```
var arr = [];
$(".browser_list ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); //add / remove class active;

    var index = arr.indexOf(this.id)
    if (index > -1) arr.splice(index, 1);
    else arr.push(this.id)
});
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ymwdvrn/

Or if you need to get the list of ID's at a later point and dont want to keep a global array:

```
var arr = $(".browser_list ul li.active").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it this way:

```js
$(function(){

  $(".browser_list li").click(function(){
       
        var arr = new Array();

       $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    
    $(".browser_list .selected").each(function(){
       
       arr.push(this.id);
    
    })
  
  })

})
```

```css
.selected
{
  background:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <li class="browser_list">
            <ul>
              <li id="config_3"> Chrome 29</li>
              <li id="config_4"> Chrome 31</li>
              <li id="config_5"> Chrome 33</li>
              <li id="config_6"> Chrome 35</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

Comment: huh? This will keep adding same elements to array that already exist